# ReferenceError: Cannot access 'setPage' before initialization

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I am trying to send State change function as prop to another components

```
const App = () => {
    const currPage = <First setPage={setPage} />;
    const [page, setPage] = useState(currPage);
    return <div className='App'>{page}</div>;
};
```

But it's giving Cannot access 'setPage' before initialization. How i can send this function as prop to other component

Comment: You need to `lift your useState` before the `currPage`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the useEffect hook

```
const App = () => {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    setPage(<First setPage={setPage} />);
  }, []);
  return <div className='App'>{page}</div>;
};
```